# download file as unknown file in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to download a pdf file from storage

```
 public function show($free)
    {
        $dl = SingleFreeDownload::find($free);
        return Storage::download($dl->file , $dl->title);
    }
```

and this is the file storage code:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
     $file = $request->file('file')->store('uploads');
    $single_download_page=[
         'file' => $file, ];
SingleFreeDownload::create($single_download_page);
}
```

when I click on download button it downloads unknown file and it not open what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First I wouldn't call the method which shall download a file `show()` I would rename it to download. Second I would check whether the file exists or not if it exists I would try to download it.

You can check whether it exists or not using this:

```
$exists = Storage::exists('myfile.jpg');
if ($exists) {
  return Storage::download($dl->file , $dl->title);
}
```

Furthermore you should check wether your input contains the name file since you are doing this:

```
 $file = $request->file('file')->store('uploads');
```

Your input needs to look like this:

```
<input name="file"...>
```

You should also show what this class does `SingleFreeDownload`.

Comment: Actully I don't know file name and there is lots of files ,what should I do?

Comment: @hadis how does your input look like, if you are posting the data through a standard form you have to name your input fields with specific names.